# Get root component ElementRef or ComponentRef angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm building modal service in angular 2. I resolve most of the issues but i have problem placing the modal component in the body element in a nice angular way. I use `DynamicComponentLoader.loadNextToLocation` function to get the modal component and place it next to the `ElementRef` that is uset in `DynamicComponentLoader.loadNextToLocation` function. But when i don't want to place the created modal inside some component i have to manipulate DOM to insert the created modal. My question is can i use the root element in my application in the modal service? I want to achieve this when specific element isn't provided as container for the modal.

```
var elementRef = DOM.query('app');
this.componentLoader.loadNextToLocation(ModalBackdrop, elementRef, backdropBindings)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
appElementRef: ElementRef;
constructor(private applicationRef:ApplicationRef, injector: Injector) {
  this.appElementRef = injector.get(applicationRef.componentTypes[0]).elementRef;
}
```

The `AppComponent` would need to provide the `elementRef` field that returns the `ElementRef` though.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6446

Answer (score 8):

To get a reference to the root component, you can inject [ApplicationRef](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/ApplicationRef-class.html):

```
constructor(private app:ApplicationRef)
{
      let element: ElementRef = this.app['_rootComponents'][0].location;
}
```

Comment: I can't use the ApplicationRef object because `loadNextToLocation` function only accepts typeof `ElementRef`object.

Comment: `let element: ElementRef = this.app['_rootComponents'][0].location;`

Answer (score 2):

The available answers didn't work for me:

- The selected answer requires the root component to have injected *ElementRef*.
- The highest-voted answer relies on accessing private variables, so it could break without warning (only public API changes are considered breaking changes and are documented)
- Other answers assume that the root component is of type *AppComponent*.

In my situation, I am developing a 3rd party library so I cannot make any assumption that the root is called *AppComponent* or that it has *ElementRef* injected.  This is what worked for me (Angular 6.1)

```
private readonly rootRef: ElementRef;

constructor(private appRef: ApplicationRef) {
  this.rootRef = appRef.components[0].injector.get(ElementRef);
}
```

I later discovered that if I tried to inject and use the service very early after Angular bootstraps, an exception was thrown because `appRef.components` is still empty. So I instead modified the code to make `rootRef` a promise that resolves with `ElementRef`.  This way the consuming code can call it immediately without raising an exception but will have to wait for the `ElementRef` to resolve:

```
private readonly rootRef: Promise<ElementRef>;

constructor(appRef: ApplicationRef) {
  this.rootRef = new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(
      () => resolve(appRef.components[0].injector.get(ElementRef)),
      100
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Though `appRef.components[0]` is undefined for me in the constructor of a service, so i had to wrap in `setTimeout` to get it to work

Comment: @delashum you're right I observed the same thing shortly after posting my original answer.  I've just updated it with what I ended up doing, if I remember well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that to get the root ElementRef, your application should be bootstrapped. And in some situations (getting ElementRef in services) we should wait for that.
My solution:

```
import {Injectable, ApplicationRef, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
  private _appElementRef: ElementRef;

  constructor(appRef: ApplicationRef) {
    appRef.registerBootstrapListener(appComponentRef => {
      this._appElementRef = appComponentRef.location;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in Angular 5.2.9

Add a public ElementRef in your root component's constructor:

```
export class AppComponent { 

constructor (public eltRef: ElementRef) { }
```

And in the component where you want to access the root, do this:

```
private rootRef: ElementRef;
constructor(private appRef: ApplicationRef) {
    this.rootRef = (this.appRef.components[0].instance as AppComponent).eltRef;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference for ElementRef in your component's constructor:

```
constructor (private applicationRef: ApplicationRef) { }
```

You can get ElementRef with either two ways:

```
let container : HTMLElement;

1) container = this.applicationRef.components[0].location.nativeElement
or
2) let viewContainer = this.applicationRef.components[0];
    container = (viewContainer.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;
```