# Angular2 Component ElementRef not working

Tags: angular

I would like to create a component in Angular 2 where I can pass in values from the HTML. I thought I would use `ElementRef`, but I can't seem to reference it without errors.

Here is my code:

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <p>Hello World</p>
    `
})
export class MyAppComponent {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
}
```

This code is just for testing if I can control or at least check the dom element of the component, but it doesn't work.

Later I want to be able to get variables from the HTML like

```
<my-app variable="value"></my-app>
```

The error I am getting is

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Can't resolve all parameters for MyAppComponent: (?). ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MyAppComponent: (?).
```

I am using the recently released 2.0.0 version (not rc)

Comment: Will you post the errors you are getting? I have read that in some cases elementRef is not supported.

Comment: Unhandled Promise rejection: Can't resolve all parameters for MyAppComponent: (?). ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MyAppComponent: (?).

Comment: Check this question, I think it will solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34970778/get-root-component-elementref-or-componentref-angular-2

Answer (score 5):

works for me.

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular2/core';
     @Component({
           selector: 'my-app',
           template: `
           <p>Hello World</p>
           {{title}}
           `
})

export class MyAppComponent {
title: string = "This Text will be in red Color";

constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
}
```

Comment: I think you might use an older version then. I'm using the 2.0.0 version. I know it was possible in older versions, but it seems like it's not possible anymore. I think we are going to have to look for a different way to pass in data from the host element.